# Appropriate phrase

Tags: usage

What could be the informal antonym for the phrase 'on vacation' ? Is it on work or on a job or something else?

For example, in this sentence below what should I fill in the blanks with. :

> I came to London not on vacation but _______.( To mean I came here with some work).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest one of the following sentences:

> I came to London not on vacation but **to work**.
>   I came to London not on vacation but **for work**.
>   I came to London not on vacation but **on business**.